# Как создать бесконечную генерацию мира в top down игре на unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Столкнулся с проблемой, что не знаю как создать бесконечное появление части мира. Не могли бы вы пожалуйста подсказать как это сделать?

Пытался сделать через OnTriggerExit2D, но быстро понял, что это глупая идея

Comment: Почему глупая и что вы имеете в виду под top down игрой?

Comment: Ну глупая потому что как по мне это ударит на производительность, а top down это 2d игра с видом сверху

Comment: google -> "unity endless runner". Принцып работы одинаковый вне зависимости от того  3д это или 2д и как там расположена камера вертикально или горизонтально

Comment: [возможные дубликаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bunity3d%5D+%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)